# Xubuntu: how to revert back the F keys

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I just installed a fresh 18.04 xubuntu on my new laptop. The <kbd>F</kbd> keys has some utility buttons for volume, screen brightness adjustments etc.

The original function keys only work with <kbd>fn</kbd> button pressed - the function keys override the <kbd>F</kbd> keys

How do I revert the keys back so these function keys only work with with <kbd>fn</kbd> key presses?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've googled a little and easiest solution was turn off active function keys in the bios. Everything works as expected now.